# creating folders based on Filename without overwriting

Tags: batch-file, directory, filenames

Working on a script whereby Staff Scans in Students Exams Certificates via Photocopier and it then places a copy to a location

the script below does the following

1) Scans to C:\users\location as filename.pdf (The Staff member will manually enter STudent number at the photocopier and it will save the file name as that)

2) Script then creates folder based on filename so here it will create a folder called /filename

3) Moves the PDF into that folder

it all works fine
however i am trying to modify it so it does not overwrite

so if for example staff member makes a typo of student1 and student1 already exists we dont want to override it

any suggestions

script is as below you can test it

```
Code:

@echo off
pushd C:\Users\location
for %%F in (*.pdf) do (
  2>nul md "%%~nF"
  >nul move /y "%%~nF*.*" "%%~nF"

)
popd
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot overwrite folder with MD so I suppose you are talking about move operation:

```
@echo off
pushd C:\Users\location
for %%F in (*.pdf) do (
  2>nul md "%%~nF"
  echo n|move /-y "%%~nF*.*" "%%~nF"  >nul 2>nul

)
popd
```

or (might depend on local settings and the expected input by `move /-y`)

```
@echo off
pushd C:\Users\location
for %%F in (*.pdf) do (
  2>nul md "%%~nF"
  echo n|move /-y "%%~nF*.*" "%%~nF" 2>&1 |find /i "0 files(s)" >nul 2>nul || (
      2>nul md "%%~nF_2"
      move "%%~nF_2*.*" "%%~nF_2" >nul 2>nul
  )

)
popd
```